# Dilation operator acting on $x$-dependent field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, commutator

I've been studying conformal field theory (CFT) and got the following "apparent" inconsistency. Let's take dilation ($D$) and translation ($P_\mu$, 4-momentum) generators that according to CFT are such that

$$
[D, P_\mu] = iP_\mu,\quad [D, \Phi(0)] = i\Delta\Phi(0),\quad \Delta \in \mathbb{R} \tag1
$$

Now we are looking for $[P_\mu, \Phi(x)]$ and $[D, \Phi(x)]$ for an arbitrary field $\Phi(x)$ (it may be scalar, spinor, vector, etc). Let's start with the first one and use the Heisenberg picture to make explicit the $x$-dependence of $\Phi$:

$$
\partial_\mu\Phi(x) = \partial_\mu e^{iPx}\Phi(0)e^{-iPx} = i[P_\mu, \Phi(x)] \implies [P_\mu, \Phi(x)] = -i\partial_\mu\Phi(x) \tag2
$$

Let's go now to the 2nd commutator:

$$
[D, \Phi(x)] = De^{iPx}\Phi(0)e^{-iPx} - e^{iPx}\Phi(0)e^{-iPx}D = e^{iPx}([\hat{D}, \Phi(0)])e^{-iPx} \tag3
$$
with
$$
\hat{D} = e^{-iPx}De^{iPx} = D - ix^\mu[P_\mu, D]\ \mbox{(obtained by Taylor expansion of exp.)}\tag4
$$

Now, using (1) and (4) into (3), the final result is
$$
[D, \Phi(x)] = i(\Delta + (x\partial))\Phi(x) \tag5
$$

But this contradicts first commutator in (1). Because of (5), $D = i(\Delta + (x\partial))$ whose commutator with $P_\mu = -i\partial_\mu$ is $[D, P_\mu] = [i(\Delta + (x\partial)), -i\partial_\mu] = -i(-i\partial_\mu) = -iP_\mu$

Isn't this a contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Q_{\xi}$ be a charge that generates some symmetry $\delta_\xi$. Then,
$$
[ Q_\xi , \Phi ] = \delta_\xi \Phi . 
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
[ [ Q_\xi , Q_{\xi'} ] , \Phi ] &=  [ Q_\xi , [ Q_{\xi'}   , \Phi ] ] + [ [ Q_\xi , \Phi ] , Q_{\xi'} ] \\
&= [ Q_\xi , \delta_{\xi'} \Phi ] + [ \delta_\xi \Phi , Q_{\xi'} ] \\
&= \delta_{\xi'} [ Q_\xi , \Phi ] - \delta_\xi [Q_{\xi'} , \Phi ]  \\
&= \delta_{\xi'} \delta_\xi \Phi - \delta_\xi \delta_{\xi'} \Phi \\
&= - [ \delta_\xi , \delta_{\xi'} ] \Phi
\end{align}
Note that the commutator of charges generates the commutator of transformations with an extra minus sign! This resolves your contradiction.

---

Let me add in a bit of information regarding symmetries and transformations. The finite version of a symmetry transformation is
$$
U \Phi U^{-1} = R(U^{-1}) \Phi
$$
where $R(U)$ is the representation of $U$ under which $\Phi$ transforms. Note that the argument of $U$ on the RHS is $U^{-1}$ and not $U$. To understand this, we consider the transformation
$$
(U_1U_2) \Phi (U_1 U_2)^{-1} = R( (U_1 U_2 )^{-1} ) \Phi
$$
Alternatively,
\begin{align}
(U_1U_2) \Phi (U_1 U_2)^{-1} &= U_1U_2  \Phi U_2^{-1} U_1^{-1} \\
&= U_1 R(U_2^{-1}) \Phi U_1^{-1} \\
&= R(U_2^{-1}) U_1 \Phi U_1^{-1} \\
&= R(U_2^{-1}) R(U_1^{-1}) \Phi .
\end{align}
It follows that,
$$
R(U_2^{-1} U_1^{-1} ) = R(U_2^{-1}) R(U_1^{-1})
$$
or equivalently, $R(U_1U_2)=R(U_1)R(U_2)$. In other words, $R$ satisfies the same group multiplication law as $U$ so it is indeed a representation.

We can now relate this to infinitesimal transformations.
$$
U = \exp [ Q_\xi ] , \qquad R(U) = \exp [  R (Q_\xi ) ] = \exp [ - \delta_\xi ] . 
$$
Note that $- \delta_\xi$ is the representation of $Q_\xi$ (*not* $+\delta_\xi$). Substituting this and expanding to first order in $\xi$, we find
$$
[ Q_\xi , \Phi ] = + \delta_\xi \Phi . 
$$
The extra minus sign between $Q_\xi$ and $\delta_\xi$ also implies that the algebra of the charges $Q_\xi$ has an extra sign compared to the algebra of $\delta_\xi$,
\begin{align}
[Q_{\xi_1} , Q_{\xi_2} ] &= Q_{\xi_3} \\
\implies R ( [Q_{\xi_1} , Q_{\xi_2} ] ) &= R ( Q_{\xi_3} ) \\
\implies [ R ( Q_{\xi_1} )  , R ( Q_{\xi_2} )] &= R ( Q_{\xi_3} ) \\
\implies [ -\delta_{\xi_1}, -\delta_{\xi_2} ] &= -\delta_{\xi_3} \\
\implies [ \delta_{\xi_1}, \delta_{\xi_2} ] &= -\delta_{\xi_3} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Then, you're telling me that I cannot take $D = i(\Delta + (x\partial))$ as generator because RHS is in fact what you call $\delta_\xi$? What's $D$'s expression then?

Comment: The idea is to think of $D$ is some operator on the Hilbert space ($\sim \int_\Sigma n^\mu x^\nu T_{\mu\nu}$) whose action (via adjoint) on another operator $\Phi$ gives us $i(\Delta+x^\mu\partial_\mu)\Phi$. You can also think of $- i ( \Delta + x^\mu \partial_\mu )$ as a representation of $D$ (note the extra minus sign).

Comment: Your last comment with $D = -i(\Delta + (x\partial))$ (with the extra minus sign) is what I've found in most books (such as Di Francesco's). Nevertheless, with this line of reasoning I find another problem. Usually, it's written that $[Q_\xi, \Phi] = \delta_\xi \Phi \equiv Q_\xi\Phi$ (because the action of the group is considered as an exponential acting on the $\Phi$), hence you can read the commutator of generator with fields as the generator times (or acting on) the field (goes on...)

Comment: So from our previous reasoning $D = -i(\Delta + (x\partial))$, but from OP's eq (5) $D = +i(\Delta + (x\partial))$ (notice "+" sign). How do we fix this?

Comment: @Vicky - You are reading it off wrong! If $[Q_\xi , \Phi ] = \delta_\xi \Phi$, then the representation for $Q_\xi$ is $-\delta_\xi$.

Comment: Then, following that logic and according to OP's eq (2), we could read $P_\mu = +i\partial_\mu$. This contradict the usual association $\vec{P} = -i\vec{\partial}$ to momentum operator in quantum  mechanics. My idea is as follows: operator transforms as $\Phi\rightarrow U\Phi U^\dagger = U\Phi$ with $U = \exp(-iaQ_\xi), a\in\mathbb{R}$. By Taylor expansion of both sides in last expression, $[Q_\xi, \Phi] = Q_\xi\Phi$. Notice that we don't end up with a minus sign in RHS of this last equation

Comment: That's the momentum operator in quantum mechanics acting on wave-functions. Here, we are dealing with the momentum operator acting on operators. They are two different things and you need to be extra careful. $P$ acts as $- i \partial$ on the bra state $\langle x |$ but it acts as $+i\partial$ on the ket state $| x \rangle$.

Comment: I believe that the issue is that usual associations such as $\vec{P} = -i\vec{\partial}$ are fallacious since $\vec{P}\in\mathcal{H}$ ($\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert space) while $ i\vec{\partial}$ is not even an operator. In fact, in QM the real relation is $\langle \vec{x}|\vec{P}|\psi(t)\rangle = -i\vec{\partial}\psi(t,\vec{x})$, no $\vec{P}\psi(t,\vec{x}) = -i\vec{\partial}\psi(t, \vec{x})$. So you can never say $D = -i(\Delta + (x\partial))$; one is an operator, the other a derivative. $D$ should be found in terms of fields (maybe with the energy-momentum tensor) as you stated previously

Comment: @Vicky I never said that $D = - i ( \Delta + x^\mu \partial_\mu )$. That's what you said. I said that $ - i ( \Delta + x^\mu \partial_\mu )$ is a _representation_ of $D$. Also $P$ is not an element of the Hilbert space, it is a linear operator on the Hilbert space so $P \in {\cal L} ( {\cal H} )$.

Comment: You're right. Could explain what you mean by a representation in this context? And how would you get an expression for $D$ in terms of actual operators in Hilbert space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135577/discussion-between-prahar-and-vicky).

Comment: I'm starting to believe your answer is not correct or I'm missing something. When you write in your second set of eqs $[ Q_\xi , \delta_{\xi'} \Phi ] + [ \delta_\xi \Phi , Q_{\xi'} ] 
= \delta_{\xi'} [ Q_\xi , \Phi ] - \delta_\xi [Q_{\xi'} , \Phi ]$, I think this is not right. From the LHS we could write $[ Q_\xi , \delta_{\xi'} \Phi ] + [ \delta_\xi \Phi , Q_{\xi'} ] 
= \delta_{\xi}\delta_{\xi'} \Phi  - \delta_{\xi'} \delta_{\xi} \Phi  = [\delta_{\xi}, \delta_{\xi'}]\Phi$ so no extra minus sign

Comment: I believe maybe that is not a big deal because, anyways, it didn't justify that a representation of charges $Q_\xi$ is $-\delta_\xi$. So my question would be: why the tensor operator transforms as $R(U^{-1})\Phi$ instead of simply $R(U)$?

Comment: What I've written is correct. Why don't you try working it out in a specific example?

Comment: Shouldn't $[Q_\xi, whatever] = \delta_\xi whatever$? So aaplying this $[Q_\xi, \delta_{\xi'}\Phi] = \delta_\xi \delta_{\xi'}\Phi$, no $  \delta_{\xi'} \delta_\xi \Phi$

Comment: The $whatever$ has to be an operator. For instance if $\delta \Phi_i = A_{ij} \Phi_j$ where $\Phi_i$ is the operator and $A_{ij}$ is a number, then $[Q , \delta \Phi_i] = [ Q , A_{ij} \Phi_j ] = A_{ij} [ Q , \Phi_j ]$

Comment: What if $A_{ij}$ is not a number but a derivative, then it's not so obvious you can take it out of the commutator. But what we do know is $[Q_\xi, operator] = \delta_{\xi} operator$ and, for sure, $\delta_{\xi'}\Phi$ is an operator

Comment: Even if it's a derivative operator you can take it out (prove this using the definition of the derivative).

Comment: If the charge in the commutor is $x$-dependent you cannot take out a derivative... what am I missing? Why is wrong my argument without taking out anything? Because I see it solid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136980/discussion-between-prahar-and-vicky).

Comment: [conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136980/discussion-between-prahar-and-vicky)